# Write a float at MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

How can I write a float to file .txt save in $f0 with MIPS

I have to try to use syscall 15 but when i load address of $f0 to $a1. It didn't work

```
li $v0, 15        # load the syscall 15 (write) code into $v0
move $a0, $s0     # move the file descriptor into $a0
move $a1, $f0     # move the float value into $a1
li $a2, 4         # set the number of bytes to write to 4 (for a float)
syscall
```

Comment: Registers don't have addresses.  The comment in `move $a1, $f0     # move the float value into $a1` is correct: it copies the value, the bit-pattern.  A write system-call needs the bytes to be in memory so there can be a pointer to them.  Store the float into some stack space.  Of course that wouldn't be text, it would be 4 bytes of binary data.

Comment: Can you help me how to solve this with code